# Stream from WebRTC input to HLS

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, http-live-streaming, kurento, janus

I need to do video streaming where the recording is happening on a browser and has to be consumed as HLS on mobile devices.

It seems I need some media server and send the camera stream as WebRTC to it. It seems [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com) and [Kurento](http://kurento.org) can do that task and output RTP streams. I'm not sure now how to convert that RTP stream to HLS, I guess I could hook ffmpeg on that RTP stream and generate HLS with MpegTS, but I'm not sure this is the right direction.

Is that the obvious way to do it? Is there any existing service to do all this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

There are several alternatives out there - all commercial in nature:

- Wowza (https://www.wowza.com/)
- Red5 (https://red5pro.com/)
- Flashphoner (http://flashphoner.com/)
- Push from Kurento directly to a CDN and letting the CDN do the conversion (there are CDNs flexible enough to allow this)

Comment: @Tashil, is there an example of this - "Push from Kurento directly to a CDN and letting the CDN do the conversion (there are CDNs flexible enough to allow this)"?

Comment: I know Limelight and CDNetworks have/should have/working on WebRTC ingest capabilities.
Janus and Kurento have plugins/addons that enable pushing streams towards RTMP which can be ingested be CDNs. Then there's the alternative today to use GStreamer.

Answer (score 1):

You can send that RTP stream to another media server like Wowza. Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kurento/wowza%7Csort:relevance/kurento/rvcO5BSJmcQ/wNDqnghCBwAJ) thread from the mailing list, for instance.